# Team separation in TFS but share projects?

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, tfs, agile

I'm new to TFS and we're loving it!  I'm having a difficult time figuring out how best to organize TFS from version control and agile/scrum/sharepoint sites, keeping isolation of teams yet sharing of code and projects.

For this scenario let's say I have three teams.  Team 1, 2, 3.  I want each team to have access to only projects they work on, and each team to have isolation for alerts and notifications, sharepoint, agile, etc.  So let's say there are 5 total projects.

```
Team 1:
--Project 1
--Project 2

Team 2:
--Project 1
--Project 4
--Project 5

Team: 3:
--Project 1
--Project 2
--Project 3
--Project 4
```

We have one collection setup, DefaultCollection.  Right now I only have one team but this doesn't give us good isolation and separation of the features.  How can I best configure TFS to keep separation of teams but not have separate code projects?  Some projects are shared and this is the point of contention - I don't know how to handle this part.

Acme Widget has X projects and then we have a "Company Shared" with X projects.  We may be working on different products such as Acme Widget 1, 2, 3 but all share and work on the Company Shared projects, i.e. Company.Utilities, Company.Windows, Company.Security.

Can someone please shed some light on how to properly configure TFS while we're early into the stages of use.  We want to go beyond just version control as mentioned above.  We want to use the Task, Bug, Alerts, Build, etc.

P.S.  If anyone is a TFS sub-contractor that helps organizations configure their TFS setup I would entertain a professional consultation and configuration.

Comment: The one way i see to organize this is using groups and their permisions, create either AD or TFS groups for teams then assign these groups to projects you need them access to either using specific permisions or part of default groups. Organizing the seperation of notifications, alerts, sharepoint will be tricky, you will go into more details about why and what on these

Answer (score 0):

Since TFS and SharePoint aren't actually holding the user accounts (they are inside Active Directory).  It would probably be easiest to create an Active Directory group for each team and place your users in that group.  You can then still keep one project collection (no need to over-architect) and then everytime you create a new project within that collection you assign the permissions to that project (TFS, Sql Reports, and SharePoint) using the Active Directory groups.  You should download the free TFS Administration tool to manage permissions and when a user joins/leaves a team then you can manage that directly in Active Directory without changing TFS, Sql Reporting or SharePoint.  This seems to be a very common approach starting when this issue arose from early SharePoint days when admins were trying to independently manage SharePoint groups and Active Directory groups.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at this:

http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/colinbird/2012/11/19/MultipleTeamsWithMicrosoftTeamFoundationServer2012VisualStudioScrumV2xUpdated1452013.aspx

This shows you how you can have multiple teams, which each of theirs board, tasks etc.

We use this in our company because its the same project, but 2 different teams. Then it works perfectly because we have the hierarchy of teams:

-- Project (level 0)

---- Team A (level 1)

---- Team b (level 1)

In that way we can assign stories or tasks to either the one of those, and if they are assigned to the project level (level 0), then it will appear on all teams.